# How to read portions of text from a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

i was wondering, is there a way to read only parts of a String in a .txt file? Like for example, if "1,5,10,20" is in my .txt file, can i tell Java to save just "1" to a certain int, then save "5" to a different int, and so on? I hope i made it clear enough!

Thanks guys!

P.S i know how to read a whole line of text in a .txt file in Java using the BufferedReader, just not how to read only certain parts of it.

Comment: Take a look at [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Scanner class provides a `nextInt` method that is used to read the next token as integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, which provides a [`Scanner#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method to read the next token as int. Now, since your integers are *comma(`,`)* separated, you need to set *comma(`,`)* as delimiter in your `Scanner`, which uses `whitespace` character as default delimiter. You need to use [`Scanner#useDelimiter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) method for that.

You can use the following code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("demo.txt"));
scanner.useDelimiter(",");

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! Ill definitely be on this site more often!

Comment: @Geforce132. You're welcome :) And more than being on this site, be in love with the documentations. They almost always have answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` class has a set of `hasNextXyz()` and `nextXyz()` methods that can be used to pick and convert values separated by some delimiter.

```
String lineOfInts = "1,5,10,15,20";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lineOfInts).useDelimiter(",");

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

See [Scanner#nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, thats realy cleared things up. Just one last thing, what would i put in the "new Scanner()" parameters to make it read the text from a file, not a String?

Comment: Since, you're reading the file using a buffered reader pass the line you get from readLine() into the Scanner. What's your file format like? If all the numbers are on one single line you can feed the Scanner your file as well by using the [Scanner(File source)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)) constructor.

Comment: Oh never mind, someone else has already answered it for me. Thanks anyway though :)!