# i try to read integer values form txt file using eclipes but its give me some error java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, user-interface

my code is based on gui, i try run on gui but i didnt make it.
public class SecondFrame extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SecondFrame frame = new SecondFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public SecondFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 612, 469);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Success !");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 38));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(201, 120, 233, 74);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JButton btnGenerateGraph = new JButton("GENERATE GRAPH");
    btnGenerateGraph.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
            try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("rn.txt");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

                String line;
                **here i try to convert line that i has read to integer**
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line));
                }
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    btnGenerateGraph.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 21));
    btnGenerateGraph.setBounds(168, 221, 245, 59);
    contentPane.add(btnGenerateGraph);
}
```

}

**this is the error:**
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/"

**my rn.txt file:**

29
44
15
17

Comment: The file RN.txt has a line with the character "/" in it and you're trying to parse it as a number. Can't do that.

Comment: 29
44
15
17 my file look like this .. no character "/"

Comment: Before your System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line)); line, Insert a System.out.println(line); That will show you what the line contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read portions of text from a .txt file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708760/how-to-read-portions-of-text-from-a-txt-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code. i'm using eclipse to create txt file. but it does not provide me with the extension of .txt. so i do it manually. copy paste to the folder and its work.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the line try to  replace all the new line characters or carriage returns etc and then perform Integer.parse.

text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are new line character in your file, due to which it is giving error while converting it into Integer as it cannot convert special characters into string.

One method to actually find out what is happening is to first just print the line content and check if it contains a blank or special character in the end of line.
So you will be able to identify at what point it is giving error.

```
String line;
**here i try to convert line that i has read to integer**
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); //Print Content as it is to check at which character you are getting error.
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line));
}
```

Similarly you can find this by using debugger in the IDE.

If you actually contains special character or new line character in the line then you can use below code to remove those characters.

```
String line;
**here i try to convert line that i has read to integer**
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = replaceAll("(\n)+", "");
    line = replaceAll("(\r)+", "");
    if(line != "" && line!= null){
        System.out.println(line); //Print Content as it is to check at which character you are getting error.
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank 4 ur explanation. yes my file actually the number is on vertical line. when i paste my input file in show horizontal line. i try ur given code. but it show me. java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Can you please paste the code in comment which you tried recently ?
Looks like reader is getting closed before reading the line or parsing the line content.
With full error message

Comment: line = replaceAll("(\n)+", "");  line = replaceAll("(\r)+", ""); <-- i try to put this 2 line code, before this i have try to read the txt file without parseint, no error generate, but it show me a simbol look like ths " 0
/


N
K
M
^

.
:
P
/
G
0

?


8
W
3
%
\

=
P
G
Q

"

Comment: this error after i put the 2 line code that u suggest : java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at SecondFrame$2.actionPerformed(SecondFrame.java:67)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)

Comment: @susan: Can you please paste the modified code , it will be helpful to understand the issue which you are getting.

Comment: @rohan it ok , im done 4 this code. my code are ok. it just when i create my txt file using eclipse. it didn't create with extension .txt so i try to do manually and its work.